# Delete ALL duplicate rows in MySQL table (Not except 1, all duplicate rows)

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove duplicate rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql)

I have a table "recipientscore" that looks like this:

- recipientid   /   messageid
- 1 / 1
- 2 / 2
- 3 / 2
- 4 / 2
- 5 / 3
- 6 / 4

What I want to do is delete all the records that appear twice or more. I do not want to keep one version of each duplicate records. It would look like this after clean up:

- recipientid   /   messageid
- 1 / 1
- 5 / 3
- 6 / 4

Would you have an idea on how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I would take distinct records into a temp table, drop the old and rename the temp to old name ;-)

Comment: I think this is _not_ a duplicate to the above question, since it's desired to drop **all** duplicates (i.e. _not_ drop all but one, and keep one).

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from recipientscore
where messageid in
(
   select * from
   (
      select messageid from recipientscore
      group by messageid
      having count(*) > 1
   ) x
)
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8e8e/1)

Comment: Hi Juergen d,
I tried your method, but I have the following error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'recipientscore' for update in FROM clause. What would you advise me to do?

Comment: Try my update. You can trick MySQL to do this with a subselect.

Comment: When I do the select, it seems to me that it just works with rows that appear twice, not 3,4,5 times...

Comment: It works. See [this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8e8e/1)

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by 'juergen d' is perfect. You could try this if u wish to keep just one unique row and delete the remaining duplicate rows.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE recipient score  ADD UNIQUE KEY idx1(messageid);
```

Comment: But that will keep one of each group, doesn't it?